# Entity framework select with group by

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, linq, sqlite

I have a simple table for images with  fields (id, path, details)
I have some images that they have the same path (different id and details).
I know the database should be normalized but this is not on me.
I want to get all the images but only once for each path.
My sql query that works is

`select * from images
Group by path
order by id`

Check [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/ff60d/1/0)

I have problem translating this to a entity framework query (linq) in VB.NET.
The only thing that I manage to make work is to get just the paths but I want the whole image (I don't care for the id but I want to have the details)

Comment: What version of entity framework are you using? Usually you can just do it  EFContext.Images.GroupBy(i=> i.Path). But in EF Core groupby wont be translated to sql and therefor the grouping happens in your application.

Comment: As @Mono said you can run it with linq simply by `GroupBy`
Also you can execute raw query with `db.ExecuteQuery(Of T)(stringQuery)` too

Comment: @Mono EF 6. Your query almost works. Somehow I have to take the FirstOrDefault

Comment: @HasanGholamali I didn't know about this. This looks interesting

Comment: Can see more information about it here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361109(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Could the person who down-voted my question to leave a comment with the reason. I would love to learn and be better next time

Comment: @HasanGholamali Thanks I have already checked the link after your first comment

Comment: FirstOrDefault will return the First hit. Without it you will have a IQueryable. If you want the full list then you might want to use .ToList() or .ToListAsync(). I would als recommend you to use .AsNoTracking() for selects if you dont plan to manipulate your data later.

Comment: @Mono Thanks. Could  you please convert your comment to an answer so I could accept it?

Comment: *I have problem translating this* It would help to know *which* problem. It always helps to include your own efforts, if only to show that you're not asking a do-my-work-for-me question. Also, the *sql query that works* does NOT work. The `select` can only contain `path`. All this makes the question unclear and lacking (visible) research effort, which is a reason to downvote (see the tooltip).

Comment: @GertArnold Although I disagree with you in most of your points, I have to admit that I should have shown my LINQ efforts (it would be just a copy and paste from LINQPad, so not so much effort). Next time I'll do it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to group with Entity Framework 6 or Core actually doesnt matter you would just use:

```
var result = EFContext.Images.GroupBy(i=> i.Path)
```

EFContext is clear. Images is the DBSet you want to group on.

If you want to actually exectute the query and get all the results I would suggest you to use:

```
var result = await EFcontext.Images.AsNoTracking().GroupBy(i=>i.Path).ToListAsync()
```

This requires of course that your method is marked as Async. Else you can just skip the await and use ToList(). Before the ToList() the returnvalue would be an IQueryable which can be used to add other conditions like Where or Select.
Once you use toList the query will be executed against the database.

AsNoTracking marks EF that you dont want to track the results and it will be (slightly) faster. That means changes you would do to the result wont be tracked by ef and when you want to save it you have to attach it before. I would recommend to always use it if you don't plan to use tracking features and updating them back to the database.